# I am trying to align <img> next to each other then <h2> below then <p> and lastly <a>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the section area in a table format, however I can't seem yo figure it out. Any possibility of assistance with this one?

I have searched w3 for guidance and checked here as well. I searched align elements side by side.

```css
#art1,
#art2,
#art3 {
  box-sizing: border - box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template - columns: repeat(auto - fit, minmax(320 px, 1 fr));
  text-align: center;
}

.articlePics {
  width: 15e m;
  border: 1 px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}

.articleHeadings {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article id="art1">
    <img src="images/ITPic.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="InformationTechnology" />
    <h2 class="articleHeadings">Information Technology</h2>
    <p>My overview</p>
    <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
  </article>
  <article id="art2">
    <img src="images/biology.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="biology" />
    <h2 class="articleHeadings">Biology</h2>
    <p>My overview</p>
    <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
  </article>
  <article id="art3">
    <img src="images/history.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="History" />
    <h2 class="articleHeadings">History</h2>
    <p>My overview</p>
    <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
  </article>
</section>
```

I need to align the three images side by side, the h2 text to display below each image, p element below the h2 element and the button in the right corner of each image. I'd also like to place a border around this like the picture  [end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h5su.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to display 3 `article` in a row

```css
#section {
  display: flex;
}
#section > article {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#art1,
#art2,
#art3 {
  box-sizing: border - box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template - columns: repeat(auto - fit, minmax(320 px, 1 fr));
  text-align: center;
}

.articlePics {
  width: 15e m;
  border: 1 px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}

.articleHeadings {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<section id="section">
  <article id="art1">
    <img src="images/ITPic.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="InformationTechnology" />
    <h2 class="articleHeadings">Information Technology</h2>
    <p>My overview</p>
    <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
  </article>
  <article id="art2">
    <img src="images/biology.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="biology" />
    <h2 class="articleHeadings">Biology</h2>
    <p>My overview</p>
    <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
  </article>
  <article id="art3">
    <img src="images/history.jpg" class="articlePics" alt="History" />
    <h2 class="articleHeadings">History</h2>
    <p>My overview</p>
    <a href="" class="moreButton">More</a>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, thank you, I never thought of adding an id to the section. Much appreciated.